# copy data from one table into another?

Tags: php, mysql

when a user signs up to my site they complete a registration form and have their details put into a table called ptb_registrations.

after this they receive an email with a verification code, they click the email link and go to the verification link, upon entering the correct code i want a query to run.

this query needs to act as an insert query that will copy the data from one table (ptb_registrations) into another (ptb_users).

can someone help me with this as it's not working and im not sure if im heading in the right direction. thanks

```
// Make a safe query
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO ptb_users (first_name, last_name, email,    
    password, dob)
SELECT firstname, lastname, email, password    
    dob
WHERE not exists (select 1 from ptb_registrations where ptb_registrations.registration_code='$verificationcode';",
                    mysql_real_escape_string($newpassword));

mysql_query($query)or die('Could not update members: ' . mysql_error());
```

Comment: **insert into table1 as select * from table2;** // make sure you have **same structure** for both the tables.

Comment: @Lucifer - you should put tihs as answer

Comment: Missing comma between `password` and `dob`, and a missing closing parenthesis for the WHERE's sub-select.

Comment: You should get a message `Could not update members: some error here` What error is shown there? But as for me, your problem is that you have no comma between password and dob in select.

Comment: i'm not getting an error

Comment: @Lucifer i am trying to do what you said, am i structuring this right: $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO ptb_users as (first_name, last_name, email,    
    password, dob)
SELECT firstname, lastname, email, password    
    dob FROM ptb_registrations
WHERE ptb_registrations.registration_code='$verificationcode';",
                    mysql_real_escape_string($newpassword));

mysql_query($query)or die('Could not update members: ' . mysql_error());

Comment: I think syntax error is there.

Comment: Try to echo $query before it is executed and show it here.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you have a lot of syntax mistakes in your query:

no comma between password and dob in select statement, From table for select statement is not specified. Also, where condition looks strange (and there is no closing bracket for `not exists` statement). As for me, you should have a query like:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ptb_users (first_name, last_name, email, password, dob)
SELECT firstname, lastname, email,'". mysql_real_escape_string($newpassword)."', dob FROM ptb_registrations
WHERE ptb_registrations.registration_code=''". mysql_real_escape_string($$verificationcode).";"
```

This query will  take a row from ptb_registrations where registration code is equal to one received from request and insert it into ptb_users (and put a new password as a user password)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, email, password,dob
into yourtablename
from (tablename)
^ you are missing something here i.e your tablename
WHERE not exists (select 1 from ptb_registrations where
ptb_registrations.registration_code='$verificationcode';",
mysql_real_escape_string($newpassword)
```

- This will create new table with same `data structure`