# Move MySQL rows between tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to insert some columns from table_a (ptb_registrations) INTO table_b (ptb_users).

At the moment I have this query which updates the columns in table b from table a, but instead of it overwriting existing information which is currently stored in ptb_users I want it to insert a new row.

My table ptb_users looks like this:

```
id (auto inc)    |   first_name   |         email   
     1                  john            john@email.com
```

...and my table ptb_registrations looks like this:

```
id (auto inc)    |   firstname   |         email   
     2                  eric            john@email.com
```

So now I want to insert the columns firstname and email from ptb_registrations into ptb_users.first_name and ptb_users.email as a new row?

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

This works on update

```
$query = "UPDATE ptb_users
SET first_name = (
  SELECT firstname
  FROM ptb_registrations
)";

mysql_query($query)or die('Could not update members: ' . mysql_error());
```

I have tried:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ptb_users.first_name = (
  SELECT firstname
  FROM ptb_registrations
)";

mysql_query($query)or die('Could not update members: ' . mysql_error());
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: You're along the right lines you want the insert select query http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html you can do it all in a single query.

Comment: I guess it's a "subquery returns more than one row..."

Comment: @jcho360 no error message

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410395/copy-data-from-one-table-into-another/15410769

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link documenting INSERT in MySQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

```
  INSERT INTO ptb_users (first_name, email)
  SELECT firstname, email
  FROM ptb_registrations;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do your insert statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO ptb_users (firstname)
  SELECT firstname
  FROM ptb_registrations
```